# Omniauth call back url for google invalid request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

After following this [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) on how to setup omniauth using google in a rails app, I noticed that the call back url was different from what I supplied in the google api console.

[image: Settings in my initializers file]

[image]

[image]

My question however is that, why is the call back url that I provided in the google API console different from the call back that google is redirecting to my app

FYI - I have the `gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'` in my Gemfile